# display two columns from a geojson as the property of an object

Tags: javascript, object, geojson

I am working on a javascript based website project utilizing geojson data. My problem is that I have an object somewhere in the code and of course there are several properties belong to that object.

Let's say that it is something as follows:

```
pointLayer:{
     title:feature.properties.parcelName
     }
```

So, when I run the app, on the basis of this piece of code the "title" which appears on the screen becomes only the Parcel Name. However I would like one more colum from the geojson in a way that both of them will be merged and displayed as an whole. Or another option might be adding just a text other than adding one more column. I wonder if that is something possible to do.
Just to make it clear, I am trying to do something like this. I know that it is completely wrong. I am giving this one below just to show what I am trying to reach.

```
 pointLayer:{
     title:feature.properties.parcelName + feature.properties.parcelNumber
     }
```

Comment: Can you share mode code? What library are you using?  What is the problem if you do it this way that you mentioned?

Comment: A little bit more clarification is required what do you want to achieve. Do you want to merge some attributes from another json to geojson properties. If this is the case just have look at https://github.com/gagan-bansal/extend-geojson-properties